# z80 crashes after executing some instructions

Tags: hardware, z80, assembly, homemade

I'm building my own Z80 computer but I'm having a very strange problem.
Consider this code:

```
ld a,0xaa
out (00),a
jp a
```

That works as expected, outputting 0xaa on port 0x00.  Now consider this code:

```
 ld a,0xaa
hello:
 out (00),a
 inc a
 jp hello
```

This outputs exactly 87 times to port 0x00, then it crashes. I took a look at the buses to see what's happening and it seems that it accesses incrementally addresses on memory when it's not needed. I read a year ago that this was a thing due to Z80's architecture, but the problem happens when this incremental access reaches 10000000(bin).  This is what I see in the logic analyser:

[image: analyzer]

The increment is happening on address 3 4 5 6 7 and 8, and when the 8th modulates, iorq stops and the CPU does weird stuff.  Can any one please help?

---

#### EDIT:

I found the answer but if you have the same or similar issue, **you should definitely** read Spektre's and tofro's answers because they list a lot of very possible problems that could cause this.

Comment: A Z80 thar flips at a 4 GiB address? 0x 1.00.00.00.00 ??

Comment: oops i meant binary

Comment: Could it be a non-CPU issue?  I.e. perhaps you are outputting to the port faster than it can receive data. This might potentially lead to bus issues. In production code, you would need some sort of delay, so the code could run the same regardless of CPU clock speed.

Comment: the cpu is not connected to anything other than a rom chip, there is nothing reading the data outputed except the logic analyzer

Comment: Are you perhaps capturing the refresh addresses rather than the data addresses to conclude that there's a linear acres pattern? And are you refreshing your RAM?

Comment: there is no ram. there is just a cpu a rom and a logic analyzer and i'm not sure what is this incremental access that i'm talking about, it cuold be the  refresh address or some register multiplexed or whatever.i just made a correlation between this access and my system crashing

Comment: Note the Z80 is outputting a refresh address when /RFSH is low - You should ignore these addresses when tracing what your program does.

Comment: thanks, now it makes much more sense. still same weird problem though

Comment: If your ROM is putting data onto the data bus when the refresh signal is active, it could be interfering with valid data read operations.  You need to ensure your memory is not performing a read operation when RFSH is low.

Comment: Which Z80 variant are you using, and what's your clock rate?  What happens if you drop your clock rate? (NMOS Z80s can run at speeds down to about 250kHz; CMOS versions as slow as you want)

Comment: The refresh register only increases the low 7 bits so can't go above 127. Out (00), A puts A on the high byte of the address bus as well, and this crash is happening roughly when that address overflows. I don't know why that would cause a crash though. Is your Z80 a later or nonstandard variant?

Comment: I Finally finished editing of my answer... Added few more points which could cause this

Comment: What's with interrupt and DMA inputs? Specifically, /INT, /NMI, /BUSRQ. You might be getting one of them unexpectedly and then CPU stucks in either non-existing interrupt handler or halts with /BUSACK asserted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the actual problem (i believe).

I was used to connecting rom's `/CS` to `A15` to have both a rom and a ram later on, on a **6502** system but as it turns out there is a handy `/MREQ` signal on the Z80.Excluding all the address decoding, the solution was to connect `/MREQ` to `/CS` of the rom.

Comment: +1 for solving and sharing... :) heh the moment A15 goes high memory goes off line meaning no more instruction is fetched ...  if the data bus is pulled down Z80 will receive `nop` until PC cross the 32K barrier and if pulled up then `rst 38h` is fetched which is most likely after your valid code fetching either `nop`s or `rst 38h` again based on the ROM  content ...

Answer (score 10):

You might be having some sort of short between A7 and some other CPU line. Your program doesn't use/need this line, but refresh does. The fact that "weird behavior" starts when A7 is toggled for the first time, definitely hints that it is connected to something it shouldn't be.

Depending on where it is connected to, if your memory fetch (from ROM) is not properly synchronized (don't read from the bus when /RFSH is low) with the /RFSH signal, you might then pick up (during the instruction fetch) stray bytes from areas where no ROM is present and thus the wrong instructions.

Comment: Except that, as per a precious commenter, doesn't the Z80's refresh counter count in its low seven bits only? Bit 7 is always whatever you loaded R with.

Comment: IT WORKS!!!! \o/ i put an or gate on /rfsh and /rd  and then going to the chip select of my rom instead of just putting cs to A15 and it worked!!!!!  i believe now i should or that with a15 too , to add a ram.

Comment: Ah, yeah. The Z80 puts A on the top half of the address bus in the OUT (00),A instruction. As soon as A wraps round to 0 this was pulling A15 low. The Z80 and ROM would then both be trying to write to the data bus at the same time, and I don't know what that would do but it probably wouldn't be good!

Comment: Open collector probably implies the logical AND if two devices output at once? I'm no expert, apply a pinch of salt to that guess.

Comment: oh man my comment earlier was stupid. just connect rom's cs to mreq

Answer (score 9):

There is a lot what could go wrong here a list of hints:

1. **code**

   I see no `ORG` directive in the code so are you sure you are placing your code in the right place of memory? Also I would feel safer with interrupts disabled. I would expect something like:

   ```
       org 0
   reset:
       di
       ld a,0xAA
   loop0:
       out (00),a
       inc a
       jp loop0
   ```
2. **[Interrupts](http://www.z80.info/zip/z80-interrupts.pdf)**

   There are `/NMI` and `/INT` pins causing interrupt (and `/RESET` is also form of interrupt too). Hope they are properly electrically handled (with pull up resistor). In case you want to use also Interrupts you need to add proper interrupt handlers for your code but those require stack so you also need **RAM** to work properly unless they are used as Watch dog for periodic reset only.

   Beware `di` disables only the `/INT` pin so `/NMI` and `/RESET` will still interfere with your code if `Low`.

   There is also the `/WAIT` and `/BUSRQ` pins that can effectively stop the **CPU** if un-handled.

   So to be more safe I would change the code a bit more:

   ```
       org 0
   reset:
       di
       ld a,0xAA
   loop0:
       out (00),a
       inc a
       jp loop0

       org 0x66
   NMI:
       jp reset
   ```

   Note that I did not use `retn` because you do not have any stack.
3. **Analyzer signal**

   As the other comments mentioned you are probing the buses of the **Z80** so you are catching everything instead of **IO** access only. That means you got address bus swapping between `pc` (program counter) and `r` (refresh) registers and **IO** address `+/-` some undefined behavior.

   The data bus is swapping between each **OP** code of your assembly code the **IO** data and also `+/-` some undefined behavior.

   So the **IO** access is only a small fraction of what you see. To identify it you should investigate `/IORQ,/RD,/WR` signals.

   The **Z80 IO** address space is officially only 8bit so probing 8th bit of address has not much sense. To move to 16 bit **IO** address space use the

   ```
   out (c),a
   ```

   which uses `bc`.
4. **What does it mean Z80 crashes exactly?**

   I am not aware of any Crash ability of **Z80**. More likely it executes `HALT` or something waiting for **HW** response that never comes ... Are you sure your logic analyzer probing does not interfere with the buses? Is the **CPU** clock still running? Is `M1` pin toggling?
5. **High frequency and circuit**

   There is also possibility that you got electrical and or timing problems. What clock are you using for **CPU**? Is your **ROM** fast enough? Do you got proper shielding of your buses and are they short enough? Do you got proper blocking ground and caps nearby to lower the impulse load on the power supply?

   If not lower your clock to more reasonable values. Also I strongly recommend to read this:

   - [Thought I found serial port - broke embedded device instead! Help?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/12824/4709)

   Also remember any un-handled input pin of **IC** is an antenna and if high frequency square pulses are nearby you can expect weird things to happen at anytime ...

   And finally if counting to a specific value stops the **CPU** it might hint you got short circuit of some higher address or data bus line with `/INT,/NMI ,/BUSRQ` or `/RESET` check for that some short circuits on **PCB** are invisible to naked eye usually scrapping the gaps between copper paths with a needle helps ...

Comment: "The Z80 IO address space is officially only 8bit" -- it's wrong because it is officially 16-bit. IN A,(XX) or OUT (XX),A officially output contents of A on higher address byte, while IN *,(C)/OUT(C),* officially output the whole BC contents on address bus. Check this: http://www.zilog.com/docs/z80/um0080.pdf

Comment: (1), (2) and (5) are extremely improbable, as the OP says his program works for 87 loops reproducably.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer but i still couldn't get it working :(. i had already pulled interupts, busrq and and wait up. i have no idea if my 5$ logic analyzer is interfering with the cpu but i see the same problem with my oscilloscope on 10X, the cpu clock is always running (i have tested 9mhz 4mhz and 600khz all showing the same issue) m1 is toggling.I have a 100n cap under the cpu and i have a stable supply.i have also triple checked my hand wired circuit .last thing, i have no idea if signals get distorted and that's why i left the project a year ago.pcb : https://imgur.com/a/DQj0b

Comment: @lvd IIRC that is not original documentation to the Z80, the 16 bit behavior was found later on as many of the additional instructions (which where not intended by the designers). The older pdfs like [this](http://datasheets.chipdb.org/Mostek/3880.pdf) shows only 8bit address ...

Comment: @H32 may be sharing your circuitry would help a bit. Also Which Z80 you got the original was only up to 4MHz.

Comment: @spektre Page 41 of the PDF you linked to "In the instructions IN A, n and OUT n, A an I/O device address n appears in the lower half of the address bus (A0-A7) while the accumulator content is transferred in the upper half of the address bus" [and similar for IN r, (C) but with contents of B]

Comment: @user3570736 hmm didn't see that. Then it is also not as old datasheet as I taught. But the timing diagrams are most likely overtaken from the old ones. If you look at them (page 21) they use only `A0-A7` would be nice to check this with the original Zilog docs to be sure but I can not find any. Another option is that you are right guys and This info was left out in the local translations of documents in my region at that time (was decades ago and English was not a common knowledge here then).